# PDFmake Ionic App not creating PDF on device

Tags: android, angularjs, pdf, ionic-framework, pdf-generation

I am working on an Ionic Application with the purpose of generating a PDF populated by a table of user information. I did this by using PDFmake.org

I have tested the application using ionic serve and it generated the PDF I wanted perfectly when used.

The problem is that when I built the application and tested it on my android device the application was not generating the PDF. I tried both `pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();` and `pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('optionalName.pdf');` and nothing worked on my device. Any ideas on what I can do to fix this problem or what I am doing wrong?

Full code of the PDF generation below:

```
$scope.people = [{
    forename: "Adam",
    surname: "Wilson",
    email: "adam.wilson@gmail.com",
    photo: " <base64 image code> "
}, {
    forename: "Kyle",
    surname: "Ryder",
    email: "kyle.ryder@gmail.com",
    photo: " <base64 image code> "
}, {
    forename: "Blake",
    surname: "Hunter",
    email: "blake.hunter@gmail.com",
    photo: "<base64 image code> "
}];

$scope.PDFBody = [];

$scope.generatePDF = function () {
    $scope.PDFBody.push([ 'Picture', 'Forename', 'Surname', 'Email Address', 'Signature' ]);
    for (i = 0; i < $scope.people.length; i++) {
        $scope.PDFBody.push([ {image: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + $scope.people[i].photo, width: 75}, $scope.people[i].forename, $scope.people[i].surname, $scope.people[i].email, '' ]);
    }
    var docDefinition = {
        pageSize: 'A4',
        pageOrientation: 'portrait',
        pageMargins: [ 40, 40, 40, 40 ],
        content: [
            {
                table: {
                    headerRows: 1,
                    widths: [ 75, 75, 75, 140, 100 ],
                    body: $scope.PDFBody
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    /*for (i = 0; i < $scope.people.length; i++) {
        docDefinition.content[0].table.body += ",[ {image: 'data:image/jpeg;base64," + $scope.people[i].photo + "', width: 200}, " + $scope.people[i].forename + ", " + $scope.people[i].surname + ", " + $scope.people[i].email + ", '' ]";
    }*/
    var number = 0;
    console.log(docDefinition);
    number = $localstorage.get('PDFnum');
    if (!isNaN(number)) {
        console.log("Pass");
        number++;
    } else {
        number = 1;
    }
    $localstorage.set('PDFnum', number);
    var docname = 'regDoc' + number + '.pdf';
    pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
    //pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download(docname);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the PDF at device, you need to do something like that, using PdfMake, Cordova File Opener 2 and Cordova File plugins:

```
getPdf() {
        let dd = null;
        dd = this.createDocumentDefinition();

         pdfMake.createPdf(dd).getBuffer((buffer) => {
         var utf8 = new Uint8Array(buffer); // Convert to UTF-8...
         let binaryArray = utf8.buffer; // Convert to Binary...

         let fileName = "file.pdf";
         let saveDir = cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory;

           File.createFile(saveDir, fileName, true).then((fileEntry) => {
             fileEntry.createWriter((fileWriter) => {
                 fileWriter.onwriteend = () => {
                   let toast = Toast.create({
                     message: 'PDF gerado com sucesso! Abrindo arquivo...',
                     duration: 2000,
                     position: 'middle'
                   });
                   toast.onDismiss(() => {
                     cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
                       saveDir+fileName,
                       'application/pdf');
                   });
                   this.navController.present(toast);
                 };
                 fileWriter.onerror = (e) => {
                     console.log('file writer - error event fired: ' + e.toString());
                 };
                 fileWriter.write(binaryArray);
             });
           });
         });
  }
```